# Laravel Populate Select Box Based on Another Select Box

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am not sure where even to start with this. I am using Laravel and LaravelCollective form fields. What I am looking to do is populate a second select box `script` (containing dates) based off of the selection in the first select box `patient` containing names. I'm assuming it will involve JavaScript somehow?

The Script model contains a `patient_id` column that links it to the Patient model, so that can be used to filter the script dates to only those that the patient owns.

**Controller**

```
$patients_select = Patient::orderBy('last_name', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('full_name', 'id');

$scripts_select = Script::orderBy('prescribe_date', 'desc')
//      ->where('patient_id', $patient_id)
    ->pluck('prescribe_date', 'id')
    ->map(function ($date, $key) {
        return date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date));
    });
```

**Blade**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('patient', 'Patient')}}
    {{Form::select(
        'patient',
        $patients_select,
        null, 
        ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select a Patient']
    )}}
</div><!-- /form-group -->

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('script', 'Script')}}
    {{Form::select(
        'script',
        $scripts_select,
        null, 
        ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select a Script']
    )}}
</div><!-- /form-group -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to listen to `change` event on event the patient select (yes, in javascript). There are at least two possibilities here:

1. Store all the "script" data in a javascript variable and, then populate options in the script select.
2. Render all the possible selects in the `.blade` file and hide them with `display: none`. Depending on the patient selection you will have to show only one script select. Be careful not to send them all when submitting the form.

Well you could also reload the page after selecting, but I doubt you wanna do that. ;)